# Count of the result of a Hibernate Criteria group by - total grouped records returned

Tags: hibernate, count, group-by, criteria, scrollableresults

I have a Criteria-based query with the following grouping:

```
Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Property.forName("xyz").group()));
```

The SQL generated is (proprietary, so cleansed):

```
select this_.XYZ as y0_ from FOO.BAR this_ WHERE [long where clause] 
    group by this_.XYZ
```

Now, conceptually, I want to wrap the query results with a count(*) such that the data never comes back from the database, just the count. Like this:

```
select count(*) from (
  select this_.XYZ as y0_ from FOO.BAR this_ WHERE [long where clause] 
      group by this_.XYZ
)
```

There could be thousands of rows that I don't need and I'm interested in high-performance, so I don't want that data coming over the network.

My Criteria-based search has numerous conditions. I cannot realistically rebuild it, so I really need to stick with Criteria.

Adding rowCount or count("xyz") doesn't help, of course, because it just reports 1 for each row.

I'm currently doing this to get the count:

```
ScrollableResults scroll = criteria.scroll();
scroll.last();
int count = scroll.getRowNumber();
```

It works, but it is taking a long time to come back with the count (on Oracle if it matters).

Can I do what I'm proposing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conceptually ,

```
select count(*) from (
  select this_.XYZ as y0_ from FOO.BAR this_ WHERE [long where clause] 
      group by this_.XYZ
)
```

is the same as

```
select count(distinct (this_.XYZ)) from FOO.BAR this_ WHERE [long where clause]
```

So , you can use `Projections.countDistinct((String propertyName))` to select the distinct propertyName  for your Criteria .

```
session.createCriteria(Foo.class)
        .add(myOrigianlCriterionObject)
        .setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("XYZ"));
```

Comment: Very cool! I was unaware of Projections.countDistinct. It worked beautifully and it is now very fast. Many, many thanks Ken.

Comment: This solution works for group by with one column. For multiple columns I wrote a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030998/2114737

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Subqueries API` and create inner criteria.

First criteria is the main criteria the group by is included to it. Row count is taken from the second criteria 100% guaranteed result.

#### First criteria

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = getNominationMainCriteria(nominationFilterDto, appraiserId);
        criteria.add(Property.forName(PROFFESIONAL_STRING + ".hcpId").eqProperty("subProf.hcpId"));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(
                Projections.groupProperty(PROFFESIONAL_STRING + "." + Constants.HCP_ID)));
```

#### Second criteria

```
Criteria nativeCriteria = getSession().createCriteria(Professional.class, Constants.SUB_PROFESSIONAL);
        nativeCriteria.add(Subqueries.propertyEq(Constants.SUB_PROFESSIONAL + "." + Constants.HCP_ID, criteria));
        nativeCriteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.rowCount()));
        rowCount = (Long) nativeCriteria.uniqueResult();
```