# hibernate criteria count over with group by

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a spring app with the `user` entity and the `users` table. I would like to get a number of all users grouped by certain fields (not per group but **in total**).
In sql It would be:

```
select
count(*) OVER () as totalRecords
  from users u
  group by
    u.first_name,
    u.last_name,
    u.age
  order by u.age DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

But I really can't do that using hibernate criteria. I could do something like:

```
public Long getTotalCount() {
        ProjectionList groupBy = projectionList();
        groupBy.add(groupProperty("firstName"), "first_name");
        groupBy.add(groupProperty("last_name"), "last_name");
        groupBy.add(groupProperty("age"), "age");
        groupBy.add(Projections.rowCount());

        return (Long) getSession().createCriteria("User")
                .setProjection(groupBy)
                .uniqueResult();
    }
```

but it's not what I want. It does counting per each group, I would like to count rows that are the result of the `group by` clause

Answer (score 0):

I just spend couple hours trying to find out a way and finally got it working.

**Disclaimer**

It is impossible to do an optimal query with plain criteria API. Optimal would be either `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( group by query here )` or `SELECT COUNT(*) OVER ()`. Neither is possible. To get an optimal query, use plain SQL if possible. For my case using plain SQL was not possible, because I have constructed a very complex logic that builds criteria and I want to use the same logic for resolving the count of aggregate also (to resolve count of pages for pagination).

**Solution**

First we add the following to all Entities that are used as base of criteria:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {

private Long aggregateRowCount;

@Formula(value="count(*) over()")
public Long getAggregateRowCount() {
    return aggregateRowCount;
}

public void setAggregateRowCount(Long aggregateRowCount) {
    this.aggregateRowCount = aggregateRowCount;
}
```

Criteria building looks like this:

```
Criteria criteria = // construct query here
ProjectionList projectionList = // construct Projections.groupProperty list here
projectionList.add(Projections.property("aggregateRowCount")); // this is our custom entity field with the @Formula annotation
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
criteria.setMaxResults(1); 
criteria.setResultTransformer(AggregatedCountResultTransformer.instance());
List<?> res = builder.criteria.list();
if (res.isEmpty()) return 0L;
return (Long) res.get(0);
```

This generates SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT groupbyfield1, groupbyfield2, count(*) over()
FROM ...
GROUP BY groupbyfield1, groupbyfield2
LIMIT 1;
```

Without LIMIT 1 the result would be

```
field1 | field2 | count
a      | b      | 12356
a      | c      | 12356
...    | ...    | 12356
```

but we add the LIMIT 1 (`criteria.setMaxResults(1);`) because the first row already contains the number of rows and that is all we need.

Finally, our AggegatedCountResultTransformer:

```
class AggregatedCountResultTransformer implements ResultTransformer {

private static final AggregatedCountResultTransformer instance = new AggregatedCountResultTransformer();

public static ResultTransformer instance() {
    return instance;
}

@Override
public Object transformTuple(Object[] values, String[] fields) {
    if (values.length == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Values is empty");
    return values[values.length-1]; // Last value of selected fields (the count)
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public List transformList(List allResults) {
    return allResults; // This is not actually used?
}
```